# mapping Hibernate query results to custom class?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Following up on a question I posted yesterday: [How to populate POJO class from custom Hibernate query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400670/how-to-populate-pojo-class-from-custom-hibernate-query)

Can someone show me an example of how to code the following SQL in Hibernate, and get the results correctly?

SQL:

```
select firstName, lastName
from Employee
```

What I'd like to do, if it's possible in Hibernate, is to put the results in their own base class:

```
class Results {
    private firstName;
    private lastName;
    // getters and setters
}
```

I believe it's possible in JPA (using `EntityManager`), but I haven't figured out how to do it in Hibernate (using `SessionFactory` and `Session`).

I'm trying to learn Hibernate better, and even this "simple" query is proving confusing to know what form Hibernate returns the results, and how to map the results into my own (base) class.  So at the end of the DAO routine, I'd do:

```
List<Results> list = query.list();
```

returning a `List` of `Results` (my base class).

Answer (score 25):

```
select firstName, lastName from Employee

query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MyResults.class));
```

You can't use above code with Hibernate 5 and Hibernate 4 (at least Hibernate 4.3.6.Final), because of an exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.github.fluent.hibernate.request.persistent.UserDto cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessMapImpl$SetterImpl.set(PropertyAccessMapImpl.java:102)
```

The problem is that Hibernate converts aliases for column names to upper case — `firstName` becomes `FIRSTNAME`. And it tries to find a getter with name `getFIRSTNAME()`, and setter `setFIRSTNAME()` in the `DTO` using such strategies

```
    PropertyAccessStrategyChainedImpl propertyAccessStrategy = new PropertyAccessStrategyChainedImpl(
            PropertyAccessStrategyBasicImpl.INSTANCE,
            PropertyAccessStrategyFieldImpl.INSTANCE,
            PropertyAccessStrategyMapImpl.INSTANCE
    );
```

Only `PropertyAccessStrategyMapImpl.INSTANCE` suits, in opinion of Hibernate, well. So after that, it tries to do conversion `(Map)MyResults`.

```
public void set(Object target, Object value, SessionFactoryImplementor factory) {
    ( (Map) target ).put( propertyName, value );
}
```

Don't know, it is a bug or feature.

**How to solve**

**Using aliases with quotes**

```
public class Results {
    
    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}

String sql = "select firstName as \"firstName\", 
    lastName as \"lastName\" from Employee";

List<Results> employees = session.createSQLQuery(sql).setResultTransformer(
    Transformers.aliasToBean(Results.class)).list();
```

**Using a custom result transformer**

Another way to solve the problem — using a result transformer that ignores method names case (treat `getFirstName()` as `getFIRSTNAME()`). You can write your own or use [FluentHibernateResultTransformer](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/transformer/FluentHibernateResultTransformer.java). You will not need to use quotes and aliases (if you have column names equal to DTO names).

Just download the library from the project page (it doesn't need additional jars): [fluent-hibernate](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate).

```
String sql = "select firstName, lastName from Employee";
List<Results> employees = session.createSQLQuery(sql)
        .setResultTransformer(new FluentHibernateResultTransformer(Results.class))
        .list();
```

This transformer can be used for nested projections too: [How to transform a flat result set using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36361630/3405171)

Comment: Nice one! By putting quotes on aliases I can use my class with ResultTransformer! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

See [AliasToBeanResultTransformer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.html):

> Result transformer that allows to transform a result to a user specified class which will be populated via setter methods or fields matching the alias names.
>
> ```
> List resultWithAliasedBean = s.createCriteria(Enrolment.class)
>             .createAlias("student", "st")
>             .createAlias("course", "co")
>             .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
>                     .add( Projections.property("co.description"), "courseDescription" )
>             )
>             .setResultTransformer( new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(StudentDTO.class) )
>             .list();
>
> StudentDTO dto = (StudentDTO)resultWithAliasedBean.get(0);
> ```

Your modified code:

```
List resultWithAliasedBean = s.createCriteria(Employee.class, "e")
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("e.firstName"), "firstName")
        .add(Projections.property("e.lastName"), "lastName")
    )
    .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Results.class))
    .list();

Results dto = (Results) resultWithAliasedBean.get(0);
```

For native SQL queries see [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html#d5e3663):

> **13.1.5. Returning non-managed entities**
>
> It is possible to apply a ResultTransformer to native SQL queries, allowing it to return non-managed entities.
>
> ```
> sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT NAME, BIRTHDATE FROM CATS")
>     .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CatDTO.class))
> ```
>
> This query specified:
>
> - the SQL query string
> - a result transformer
>     The above query will return a list of `CatDTO` which has been instantiated and injected the values of NAME and BIRTHNAME into its corresponding properties or fields.

Comment: Funny, I can reproduce the problem with Hibernate 5.1. The transformer `Transformers.aliasToBean(CatDTO.class)` doesn't work. I just tested with my own transformer before :) Try to figure out why so.

Comment: It is much more funny, I was right with the aliases. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37423885/3405171

Answer (score 7):

You need to use a constructor and in the hql use new. I let you the code example taken from this question:  [hibernate HQL createQuery() list() type cast to model directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339504/hibernate-hql-createquery-list-type-cast-to-model-directly)

```
class Result {
    private firstName;
    private lastName;
    public Result (String firstName, String lastName){
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
   }
}
```

then your hql

```
select new com.yourpackage.Result(employee.firstName,employee.lastName) 
from Employee
```

and your java (using Hibernate)

```
List<Result> results = session.createQuery("select new com.yourpackage.Result(employee.firstName,employee.lastName) from Employee").list();
```

Answer (score 3):

YMMV but I've found that the key factor is you must make sure to alias every field in your SELECT clause with the SQL "AS" keyword. I've never had to use quotes around the alias names. Also, in your SELECT clause use the case and punctuation of the actual columns in your database and in the aliases use the case of the fields in your POJO. This has worked for me in Hibernate 4 and 5.

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

...

String sqlQuery = "SELECT firstName AS firstName," +
        "lastName AS lastName from Employee";

List<Results> employeeList = sessionFactory
        .getCurrentSession()
        .createSQLQuery(sqlQuery)
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Results.class))
        .list();
```

If you have multiple tables you can use table aliases in the SQL as well. This contrived example with an additional table named "Department" uses more traditional lower case and underscores in database field names with camel case in the POJO field names.

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT e.first_name AS firstName, " +
        "e.last_name AS lastName, d.name as departmentName" +
        "from Employee e, Department d" +
        "WHERE e.department_id - d.id";

List<Results> employeeList = sessionFactory
        .getCurrentSession()
        .createSQLQuery(sqlQuery)
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Results.class))
        .list();
```

Comment: It was very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I love you man, if I could I would give this answer 100 points.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.ClassCastException: "CustomClass" cannot be cast to java.util.Map.`

This issue appears when the columns specified in SQL Query doesn't match with the columns of the mapping class.

It may be due to:

- Non-matching casing of column name or
- The column names are not matching or
- column exist in query but missing in class.

Answer (score 1):

JPQL case from hibernate 5.4:

```
Query<Employee> queryList = session.createQuery("select new xxx.xxx.Employee(e.firstName,e.lastName) from Employee e", Employee.class);
List<Employee> list = queryList.list();

Query<Long> queryCount = session.createQuery("select count(*) from Employee", Long.class);
Long count = queryCount.getSingleResult();
```

- The select statement in JPQL is exactly the same as for HQL except that JPQL requires a select_clause, whereas HQL does not.
- setResultTransformer @Deprecated It should not be used
- more on [Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select)

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a native query, all answers here use deprecated methods for newer versions of Hibernate, so if you are using 5.1+ this is the way to go:

```
// Note this is a org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery NOT Query.
NativeQuery query = getCurrentSession()
                .createNativeQuery(
                        "SELECT {y.*} , {x.*} from TableY y left join TableX x on x.id = y.id");


// This maps the results to entities. 
query.addEntity("x", TableXEntity.class);
query.addEntity("y", TableYEntity.class);

query.list()
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing (exist this type of Challenges working with hibernate)

1. Custom Queries
2. Custom Queries with Optional Parameters
3. Mapping Hibernate Custom query results to Custom class.

I am not saying about custom EntityRepository interface which extends JpaRepository on SpringBoot which you can write custom Query with @Query -> here you can't write query with optional params 
e.g. if param is null don't append it in query string. And you can use Criteria api of hibernate but it not recommended in their documentation because of performance issue...

But exist simple and error prone and performance good way...

Write your own QueryService class which are methods will get
 string(answer for first and second problem) sql and will map result to
 Custom class (third problem) with it's any association @OneToMany, @ManyToOne ....

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class HibernateQueryService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateQueryService.class);
    private JpaContext jpaContext;

    public HibernateQueryService(JpaContext jpaContext) {
        this.jpaContext = jpaContext;
    }

    public List executeJPANativeQuery(String sql, Class entity){
        log.debug("JPANativeQuery executing: "+sql);
        EntityManager entityManager = jpaContext.getEntityManagerByManagedType(Article.class);
        return entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, entity).getResultList();
    }

/**
 * as annotation @Query -> we can construct here hibernate dialect 
 * supported query and fetch any type of data
 * with any association @OneToMany and @ManyToOne.....
 */
    public List executeHibernateQuery(String sql, Class entity){
        log.debug("HibernateNativeQuery executing: "+sql);
        Session session = jpaContext.getEntityManagerByManagedType(Article.class).unwrap(Session.class);
        return session.createQuery(sql, entity).getResultList();
    }

public <T> List<T> executeGenericHibernateQuery(String sql, Class<T> entity){
    log.debug("HibernateNativeQuery executing: "+sql);
    Session session = jpaContext.getEntityManagerByManagedType(Article.class).unwrap(Session.class);
    return session.createQuery(sql, entity).getResultList();
}


}
```

Use case - you can write any type condition about query params

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<ArticleDTO> findWithHibernateWay(SearchFiltersVM filter){

        Long[] stores = filter.getStores();
        Long[] categories = filter.getCategories();
        Long[] brands = filter.getBrands();
        Long[] articles = filter.getArticles();
        Long[] colors = filter.getColors();

        String query = "select article from Article article " +
            "left join fetch article.attributeOptions " +
            "left join fetch article.brand " +
            "left join fetch article.stocks stock " +
            "left join fetch stock.color " +
            "left join fetch stock.images ";

boolean isFirst = true;

        if(!isArrayEmptyOrNull(stores)){
            query += isFirst ? "where " : "and ";
            query += "stock.store.id in ("+ Arrays.stream(stores).map(store -> store.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))+") ";
            isFirst = false;
        }

        if(!isArrayEmptyOrNull(brands)){
            query += isFirst ? "where " : "and ";
            query += "article.brand.id in ("+ Arrays.stream(brands).map(store -> store.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))+") ";
            isFirst = false;
        }

        if(!isArrayEmptyOrNull(articles)){
            query += isFirst ? "where " : "and ";
            query += "article.id in ("+ Arrays.stream(articles).map(store -> store.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))+") ";
            isFirst = false;
        }

        if(!isArrayEmptyOrNull(colors)){
            query += isFirst ? "where " : "and ";
            query += "stock.color.id in ("+ Arrays.stream(colors).map(store -> store.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))+") ";
        }

        List<Article> articles = hibernateQueryService.executeHibernateQuery(query, Article.class);


      /**
        *  MapStruct [http://mapstruct.org/][1]
        */
        return articles.stream().map(articleMapper::toDto).collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a result transformer that ignores case:

```
package org.apec.abtc.dao.hibernate.transform;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessStrategyBasicImpl;
import org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessStrategyChainedImpl;
import org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessStrategyFieldImpl;
import org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessStrategyMapImpl;
import org.hibernate.property.access.spi.Setter;
import org.hibernate.transform.AliasedTupleSubsetResultTransformer;

/**
 * IgnoreCaseAlias to BeanResult Transformer
 * 
 * @author Stephen Gray
 */
public class IgnoreCaseAliasToBeanResultTransformer extends AliasedTupleSubsetResultTransformer
{

    /** The serialVersionUID field. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3779317531110592988L;

    /** The resultClass field. */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private final Class resultClass;
    /** The setters field. */
    private Setter[] setters;
    /** The fields field. */
    private Field[] fields;
    private String[] aliases;

    /**
     * @param resultClass
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public IgnoreCaseAliasToBeanResultTransformer(final Class resultClass)
    {
        if (resultClass == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("resultClass cannot be null");
        }
        this.resultClass = resultClass;
        this.fields = this.resultClass.getDeclaredFields();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTransformedValueATupleElement(String[] aliases, int tupleLength) {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Object transformTuple(final Object[] tuple, final String[] aliases)
    {
        Object result;

        try
        {
            if (this.setters == null)
            {
                this.aliases = aliases;

                setSetters(aliases);
            }
            result = this.resultClass.newInstance();

            for (int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++)
            {
                if (this.setters[i] != null)
                {
                    this.setters[i].set(result, tuple[i], null);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (final InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            throw new HibernateException("Could not instantiate resultclass: " + this.resultClass.getName(), e);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void setSetters(final String[] aliases)
    {
        PropertyAccessStrategyChainedImpl propertyAccessStrategy = new PropertyAccessStrategyChainedImpl(
                                                                                                         PropertyAccessStrategyBasicImpl.INSTANCE,
                                                                                                         PropertyAccessStrategyFieldImpl.INSTANCE,
                                                                                                         PropertyAccessStrategyMapImpl.INSTANCE
                                                                        );

        this.setters = new Setter[aliases.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++)
        {
            String alias = aliases[i];
            if (alias != null)
            {
                for (final Field field : this.fields)
                {
                    final String fieldName = field.getName();
                    if (fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase(alias))
                    {
                        alias = fieldName;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                setters[i] = propertyAccessStrategy.buildPropertyAccess( resultClass, alias ).getSetter();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public List transformList(final List collection)
    {
        return collection;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if ( this == o ) {
            return true;
        }
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) {
            return false;
        }

        IgnoreCaseAliasToBeanResultTransformer that = ( IgnoreCaseAliasToBeanResultTransformer ) o;

        if ( ! resultClass.equals( that.resultClass ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        if ( ! Arrays.equals( aliases, that.aliases ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = resultClass.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + ( aliases != null ? Arrays.hashCode( aliases ) : 0 );
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks promising, but how do we go about using this, please provide an example