# How to fetch data from joined tables straight to a class?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Is it possible to retrieve data from a query straight into the `EmployeeForm`?

Query as stored procedure empdata

```
SELECT a.name,b.username,b.password FROM Tbemployee left join Tbuser
```

Code

```
   List<EmployeeForm> form = new ArrayList<EmployeeForm>();
    EmpDB service = (EmpDB) RuntimeAccess.getInstance().getServiceBean(
    service.begin();
    Session session = service.getDataServiceManager().getSession();
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("EXEC empdata");
    List list = query.list();
    formList = list;
```

This gives me an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.emp.form.EmployeeForm
```

Comment: Use [JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html) for object/relational mapping.

Comment: Are you saying I can make entities that is not a table in the database?

Comment: Yes use `ResultTransformer` for that.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420401/mapping-hibernate-query-results-to-custom-class) and [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.html)  for reference.

Comment: thank you sir resulttransformer is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `ResultTransformer`

The other option is to cast to `List<Object[]>` which contains rows with columns from the query result, and then iterate and extract data(more work).

The transformer could be something like:

```
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(EmployeeForm.class));
```

Comment: This works but when I add a date column It gives me an error "org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - expected type: java.util.Date, actual value: java.lang.String" does this resulttransformer returns string for all values?

Comment: No, it works with dates as well, if your column on DB side is date.

Comment: The error is gone now. My date is datetime so I used cast to convert it into date which I think caused the error? Does it also accept null values ?

Comment: I'ved tried it on all common datatypes only exception was on boolean. It gives me an error if boolean is null. But case when null is applicable in this scenario. Thank you sir.

Comment: Use `Boolean` wrapper, not `boolean` primitive.