# Hibernate createQuery resultset Mapping(Spring boot)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am firing the HQL Join query

```
@Override
public List<Object> getCourseIdWithStatus(int courseId, String status) {

    String queryString = "select sc.courseId, sc.name, sct.streamId from Course "
            + "sc join CoursesTypeInformation sct ON(sc.courseId = sct.courseId)"
            + " where sc.courseId = ?1 and sc.status = ?2 and sct.status = ?3";
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
    query.setParameter(1, courseId);
    query.setParameter(2, status);
    query.setParameter(3, status);
    return (List<Object>)query.getResultList();
}
```

This is a **HQL Query not a native SQL**

Now I have a pojo class

```
public class BasicData {

    private int courseId;

    private String name;

    private int streamId;

    .. setters and getters

}
```

I want to map result of query to POJO. WHat should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mapping Hibernate query results to custom class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420401/mapping-hibernate-query-results-to-custom-class)

Comment: The solution is defined for Native SQL not HQL.

Comment: I think you can directly populate your custom object if you are using HQL. Try this: (List<YourCustomObject>)query.getResultList();

Comment: tried it, not working java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.domain.customDTO.BasicData

Answer (score 0):

there is many ways to achieve this, one of it by creating constructor in your POJO class 
here some example taken from my code :

**POJO :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_KCT_SPL_STOCK_DTL")
public class TblKctSplStockDtl implements Serializable{
   ...
   public TblKctSplStockDtl(String reclaim, BigDecimal){ 
    this.reclaim = reclaim;
    this.tonnage = tonnage;
   }
  ...
}
```

---

**HQL :**

```
String hql = "select new TblKctSplStockDtl(t.reclaim, sum(t.tonnage)) from TblKctSplStockDtl t "
            + "where t.idStock = :idStock and t.state = 'IN' "
            + "group by t.reclaim ";

Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
```